# Firebase datasnapshot getValue() does not find specific data in the database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an error which makes no sense (for me, at least). 
In my application, users can sell stuff. So i am storing what they want to sell in the firebase database. This is how my application write the data to the firebase:

The "Items" class constructor (Getters / Setters and String variables is there also):

```
public Items (String title, String info, String photoItem, String userid){
    this.id = userid;
    this.title = title;
    this.info = info;
    this.photoItem = photoItem;
}
```

When the user creates a new Item, this is code will run:

```
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(titleInfo) || !TextUtils.isEmpty(infoInfo)) {
            String id = databaseItems.push().getKey();

            Items items = new Items(titleInfo, infoInfo, imageEncoded, user.getUid());

            //Trenger fiks:
            databaseItems.child(id).setValue(items, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                public void onComplete(DatabaseError error, DatabaseReference ref) {
                    if(error == null) {
                        Toast.makeText(NewItemsActivity.this, "Item Added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        startActivity(new Intent(NewItemsActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class));
                    }
                    else {
                        Log.d("Status:", "No databaseconnection");
                        Toast.makeText(NewItemsActivity.this, "Error: Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

When the user has created a new item, the data will appear in the database like this:

```
"Items": {
  "Some key": {
    "Id": "The user ID",
    "title": "Some title",
    "photoitem": "Some string",
    "info": "Some info" 
}
```

Everything above works perfectly, and i've also retrieved the data and put it into a recyclerview.

The problem is: 
I want to do something with the Id (this is the firebase userid ( .getUid()), 
but for some reason it returns null.

If I made myself unclear, the correct user.getUid() is saved to the database, the problem is retrieving it.

This is where I get the data:

```
private void prepareItemData() {
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference dbref = database.getReference();

    dbref.child("Items").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.d(TAG, "in onChildAdded");
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "In postSnapshot");
                data.clear();
                for(DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Items item = ds.getValue(Items.class);
                    data.add(new Items(item.getTitle(), item.getInfo(), item.getPhotoItem(), item.getId()));
                    Log.d(TAG, item.toString());
                    Log.d(TAG, item.getTitle());
                    Log.d(TAG, item.getInfo());
                    Log.d(TAG, item.getPhotoItem());

                    // Cant find Id! 
                    // Log.d(TAG, item.getId());
                    // The app crashes when trying to log the item.getId() 

                }
                iAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError firebaseError) {

        }


    });

}
```

I am logging the title, info and photoitem, which all print out the string. 
But if I add: Log.d(TAG, item.getId());, the application crashes, and throws the NullPointerException.

Here is the error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: no.hiof.remir.smalltrades, PID: 23754
java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:168)
at no.hiof.remir.smalltrades.Activities.MainActivity$4.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:204)
at com.google.firebase.database.Query$1.onDataChange(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbmz.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbnz.zzYj(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzboc$1.run(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

If anyone know why this error may occur, it would be really helpful. This problem has been giving me a headache for some time now.

Comment: If you are asking from logicat then that particular error is caused by your try to print out message with `null`

Comment: No, that code works fine. The error occurs on the line with Log.d(TAG, item.getId()); As long as i remove that Log.d, everything works fine. 
No idea why item.getId(); returns null, when i can see it's saved in the database.

Comment: Then remove the that line of code if that causing the issue or use it to print value for example `Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(item.getId());` and you will not get `NullPointerException`

Comment: Okay, so your suggestion seems to work! Thanks! May i ask what the difference is between: 
    Log.d(TAG, item.getId()); 
and
    Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(item.getId()));
When item.getId is a string?

Comment: `Log` can't directly print null message and `String` can take a null value. But you can print out `valueOf` and if it is null `Log` will just simply print out `null` in your logcat.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a problem with the way you have defined the fields and getters/setters for your `Items` class. Can't say for sure, because you did not post the full code for `Items`.  Or it could be you have some old values in your database created from a previous version of `Items`.

In the database snippet you posted, the user ID field is capitalized, `Id`.  `getId()` is looking for lowercase `id` and will return null because that field is not present.

The constuctor for `Items` has `this.id`, which suggests the current version of `Items` uses `id`, `getId()` and `setId()`, which are consistent and will work. The `Id` value in the database is likely old.  You will need to go through the database and change all instances of `Id` to `id`.

Comment: Yeah, Yupi has already helped me with this. I thought the Id (capitalized "I") might be the problem, but it was'nt. 
Solved by changing item.getId(); with String.valueOf(item.getId());
Still dont know why item.getId() returns null, and the other does'nt, but know it works. Thanks tho!